# Unable to open Cloud9 workspace

Tags: cloud9-ide

For the past couple of days I am unable to connect to a hosted PHP project workspace in Cloud9 IDE. When I open it, it tries connecting for about 1min then gives me the toast message: "Disconnected: Could not reach your workspace". Other workspaces load fine, so the issue seems to be specific to this workspace.

The only thing it shows is 5 open tabs, one of which had unsaved alterations.

Is there any troubleshooting I can do or any way to "reset" the workspace without losing the files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have any issues with your Cloud9 workspace, if you haven't done so already, please send an email to the Cloud9 Support team via https://support.c9.io. We'll pick it up asap!